# Why Can My Database Not See This Database Column?

Tags: mysql, alias

I have a table called "customers". It contains a column called "id" and for some amazing reason, I am getting the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'c.id' in 'on clause'
```

When I do this join:

```
SELECT c.co_name, p.name
FROM `customers` as c, `products` as p, `customer_product` as cp
Join `products`
On c.id = cp.customer_id
```

I have also tried removing the alias and writing out customers.id and I still get the error.

Why am I getting the error - what have I done wrong ?

Many Thanks !

Comment: The error message you posted doesn't appear to relate to the query you've posted. There's not much to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably failing as you are using alias and full table.. pick one...  Also, you will get a Cartesian result as you don't have anything tying between cp and p tables..   POSSIBLE solution.

```
SELECT 
      c.co_name, 
      p.name
   FROM 
      customers c
         JOIN customer_product cp
            on c.id = cp.customer_id
            Join products p
               on cp.product_id = p.id



Clarification per request.
```

I have a style I like to use for doing my SQL-based queries.  If you click on my image of the answer (or anyone for that matter), it will take you to their profile / history.  Then if you click on the MySQL tag, it will take you to a list of all answers I've provided for MySQL (or whatever tag you are interested in from me or any other user).  From that, look at the pattern of styling of my answers.

I like to use indentation as a visual representation of how table "A" correlates to "B" and from "B" to "C" as can be seen here.  You used a cross between comma separated tables with no defined JOIN and then a join only on the third table.  This means only the JOIN condition was applied.

When I did the query, I listed the primary table first, JOIN to the second and immediately identify the ON condition between the FIRST (left-side) table and the SECOND (right-side) table.  Since you have a link-table (identifying customers and products), the first criteria joined from the customer table to the link table by the customer.  So now, you need to get from the link table to the product table.  So now, the indentation moves the product table further in and now the FIRST (left-side) table is the LINK (customer_products) table joined to the SECOND (right-side) table of products.  Now the ON condition between those.

So now, relations are established between A-B and B-C.

Once this is done, then you can get whatever columns to be returned and THEN apply any other criteria / group by / order by conditions.  Note, If I had additional criteria at one of the secondary (or deeper) levels, I would add the criteria exactly at that location.  This way, when dealing with left-join conditions, I am not accidentally turning it to an INNER join by putting the criteria in the WHERE clause.

Hope this and some other answers that you can look at help in your future querying.

Comment: apologies that was an artefact from some previous testing. I have changed it to c.id for consistency and I still get the error. I will try your suggested code.

Comment: Flippin' heck your code works !!! Can you please explain what I was doing wrong and what you did right so I don't do it again ? THANKS !

Comment: @Vince, thanks for the upvote/check, and I've revised my answer for clarification and how to look at other answers I've provided for styling of SQL that I like to use.